# Leetcode Two sum problem - Why doesn't my condition work

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to solve the following problem statement:

> Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such
> that they add up to a specific target.
>
> You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and
> you may not use the same element twice.

My working code is below

```
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    let comp = {};
    for(let i =0; i<nums.length; i++){
        let match = target - nums[i]
        if(comp[match]>=0){
            return [comp[match], i]
            console.log(comp)
        }
        else{
            comp[nums[i]]= i
        }
        console.log(comp)

    }
};
```

My question is, why doesn't my code work if I remove `comp[match]>=0` in the `if` statement and use `comp[match]` instead?

**Example (non-working) Snippet**:

```js
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
  let comp = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    let match = target - nums[i]
    if (comp[match]) {
      return [comp[match], i]
      console.log(comp)
    } else {
      comp[nums[i]] = i
    }
    console.log(comp)

  }
};

twoSum([2, 7, 11, 15], 9)
```

Comment: What do you mean remove `comp[match]>=0` ? Your if-statement would look like `if()` and you'd get a syntax error

Comment: For what its worth, I gave an explanation to this algorithm [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59612976/two-sum-leetcode-explanation-hashmap-javascript/59613430#59613430) the other day which might help you understand how it works in more depth?

Comment: @NickParsons I mean writing ```if(comp[match])``` instead of writing ```if(comp[match]>=0)```

Comment: Are any of the numbers negative?  What are `nums`?    `if (comp[match])` will evaluate differently from `if (comp[match] >= 0)` if `comp[match]` is negative.

Comment: @Amy the first test case #s are 2,7,11,15 and target is 9

Comment: i get output undefined when i run it without the ```comp[match>=0]```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind `comp` is to store the indexes of the values previously seen while you're looping through your array of numbers. This means that it is possible for a key in your object to point to the index `0`.

In JavaScript, `0` is considered [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), so when put into a `if` statement, it will skip the `if` block as it is considered `false`, and instead, execute the `else` block.

```js
if(0) {
  console.log("truthy"); // doesn't execute
} else {
  console.log("falsy");
}
```

So, if you were to use `if(comp[match])` and `comp[match]` was to give you the index value of `0`, your `else` block would trigger, when instead, you actually need your `if` block to trigger (as you have previously seen a number which you can now add with the current number). That's why the following works as expected:

```
if(comp[match] >= 0)
```

In this scenario, if `comp[match]` returns back the index value of `0`, the code in your if-block will be triggered as needed. It is possible for `comp[match]` to return `undefined` though. In this case, your else block will trigger so your code will work fine (as `undefined >= 0` is false). However, if you want to make your condition more readable you can instead use:

```
if(conp[match] !== undefined)
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot about zero can be the index which is falsy. If you don't mind expanding. When can we get an undefined situation?