# map[complement] === undefined vs !map[complement]

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am solving the following leetcode [question](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum-ii-input-array-is-sorted/) and have the solution below

```
const twoSum = (numbers, target) => {
    let map = {}
    let result = []
    for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        let complement = target - numbers[i]
        if (map[complement] === undefined) {
            map[numbers[i]] = i
        } else {
            result[0] = map[complement] + 1
            result[1] = i + 1
        }
    }
    return result
};
```

If I replace `map[complement] === undefined` with `!map[complement]` I return an empty array. In my mind both should return `true`. Why does the latter breaks my code?

Comment: Does `map[complement]` produce a zero at any point? [All falsey values in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19839952)

Comment: @VLAZ It certainly does. The constraint is [-1000, 1000].

Comment: This also might help clarify some things: [Leetcode Two sum problem question about why my code doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59674537/5648954)

Comment: _"I am solving the following leetcode question..."_ - Please add the relevant parts of the question _in_ your question here. If the leetcode site dies your question should still be complete and reproducible.

Comment: @Andreas to be honest, it's probably irrelevant for a [mcve] - if it boils down to just truthy/falsy, then it should just be asking "why `if (!obj[x] === undefined)` doesn't behave the same as `if (!obj[x])` when `obj[x]` is `0`" or something along those lines. We don't need the whole algorithm and the problem it's solving if it's just literally that one line that's relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map[complement] === undefined` only becomes `true` when there is no element with the key equal to `complement` while `!map[complement]` becomes `true` in all the cases where its result is a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value.

Falsy values include but are not limited to, `""`, `false`, `undefined`, `null`, `0`, `-0`, etc.

In other words, the first case is a sub set of the second.