# Unexpected , value gives me an undefined answear

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve a problem , Two Sum for those who know it , I started learning JavaScript coming from Lua , and I am stuck , I don't know why the function returns "undefined" I fill like the variable is defined

```
var num = [2, 7, 11, 15]

function numbers(target) {
  var idx = {}
  num.forEach(function(n, i) {
    var j = idx[target - n]
    if (j) {
      var res = '[ ${j} ${i} ]'
      return res
    }
    console.log(n)
    idx[n] = i
  })
}
console.log(numbers(9))
```

output:

```
2
7
11
15
undefined
```

Problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/

Comment: `numbers` function returns `undefined` ... which you log to the console

Comment: How should I go abt it then?

Comment: Instead of `console.log(numbers(9))`, just call `numbers(9)`.

Comment: If you're logging _within_ the function don't wrap it with a console.log.

Comment: Don't use `.forEach()` if you want to break out of the "loop" with `return`

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: You return something from your `forEach` callback `function (n, i)` (which is ignored), not from your outer `function numbers (target)`. Better use a regular `for` loop so you don't need a nested function.

Comment: By the looks of the task the function is also expecting the array as an argument.

Comment: I was looking for loops , you know how in Phyton you can do for i,v in , I want something like that , but in js , and I can't seem to find it

Comment: @JaromandaX I guess you pass a number to the function and it has to return two index from the array where the `num[x] + num[y] = number you passed`

Comment: @ask4you - so ... the expected output is ... "number you passed"?

Comment: Yes , correct..

Comment: I need the output to give me two numbers , when you add them together you get the target

Comment: @JaromandaX The ouput has to an array of index.

Comment: @ask4you that is meaningless

Comment: @TDumitru ... exactly what output do you require. A vague description isn't helpful

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution I think , I don't think it's the best one , but it works

Code:

```
var nums = [2,7,11,15]
var twoSum = function(target) {
    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        for (let j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
            if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target) {
                return [i, j]
            }
        }
    }
}
console.log(twoSum(9))
```

Comment: Yeah, this approach works but doesn't have good time complexity. Usually, with questions on leetcode your goal is to think of ways to make them efficient. See the explanation on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59613430/5648954) here (below the last code snippet) for why you should try and go with the object approach.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues:

1. Your current code is returning a string `'[ ${j} ${i} ]'`, you need to return an array `[j, i]`.
2. Using `return` from within `.forEach()` does not return from your `numbers` function, it instead returns from the inner callback function `function(n, i) {` which doesn't do much except just skips to the next item in the loop. You need to change your `forEach()` to a regular `for` loop so that when you `return` you return from your `numbers` function, and not an inner callback.
3. Your condition `if (j) {` is flawed. Consider if `j` is `0`, which occurs when the number you're after to add to the current number `n` is at index `0`. In this case, your if-block won't run because `0` is considered [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy). Your condition should instead be more specific by checking that it returned a value `if(j !== undefined)`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59674976/5648954) for more details about the condition.
4. You should be passing `nums` into your `numbers()` function rather than relying on a global variable to exist for your function to work correctly.

Example of modified code:

```js
function numbers(nums, target) {
  const idx = {}
  for(let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    let n = nums[i];
    let j = idx[target - n]
    if (j !== undefined) {
      return [j, i];
    }
    idx[n] = i;
  }
}

console.log(numbers([2, 7, 11, 15], 9));
console.log(numbers([3,2,4], 6));
console.log(numbers([3,3], 6));
```

See the answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59613430/5648954) for more details for solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
   var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    let newArr = nums
    let sum = 0
    outputArr = []
    for(let i = 0 ; i < nums.length ; i++){
        let val1 = nums[i]
        for(let j = 0 ; j < newArr.length ; j++){
           if(i !==j) {
            let val2 = newArr[j]
             if(val1 + val2 === target) {
                 sum = val1 + val2
                 outputArr.push(i)
                 outputArr.push(j)
                 break;
             }
        }
        }
        if(sum === target)
        break;
    }
        return outputArr
};
```

try this If helps and you need explanation I will help you