# loop with strange return function?

Tags: python, loops

I have a question about the below code, particularly the 6th line; is it right to say that it is returning the index of `target-nums[I]`? If so, why is there another `I` after it?

Also, what is `comp[nums[I]] = I` doing? Is it assigning values of nums into comp if it is not in comp already?

Finally, what is the final return [ ] doing in the last line of code?

```
def TwoSum(nums, target):
    comp = {}            

    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if (target - nums[i]) in comp:
            return [comp[target - nums[i]],i]

        comp[nums[i]] = i

    return []

print(TwoSum(nums,target))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it right to say that it is returning the index of target-nums[I]?
> If so, why is there another 'I' after it?

It is returning a list of two items, the first item being `comp[target - nums[i]]`, and the second item being `i`. It's the same idea as:

```
def addAndSubtract(x, y):
    return [x+y, x-y]
```

Above, we return a list, the first item in the list is the value of evaluating `x+y` and the second value is the result of evaluating `x-y`.

> Also, what is comp[nums[I]] = I doing? Is it assigning values of nums into comp > if it is not in comp already?

This will assign the value of `nums[i]` as a key in your `comp` dictionary and assign it the value of `i`. It essentially stores the current value in `nums` and along with its index. This does two things:

1. Allows you to easily and quickly check if you have seen a given number yet by checking if it is a key in your `comp` dictionary
2. Allows you to check where that number was last seen in your list.

The `comp[nums[i]] = i` occurs each time your for loop runs, so it will do it for all numbers, in your list, unless it returns in your if-statement. If you happen to encounter the same number again (which is already in your list), then this assignment will simply overwrite the value with the current index of the current number (ie: `i`).

> Finally, what is the final return [ ] doing in the last line of code?

The purpose of this is to return an empty list. It is just a way to signify that no result was found. You will only reach that return when you have iterated through all the numbers in your list and not returned from within your for loop, thus indicating no sum can be made to reach the `target`.

I explain how this algorithm works in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59612976/two-sum-leetcode-explanation-hashmap-javascript/59613430#59613430), so you might want to check that out if you need more of an explanation. Although the question is a JavaScript question, the logic explained is the exact same as this.

Comment: Thanks for sharing- how did you get from 'I' to x-y though?

Comment: @PatrickChong the first function is showing a completely different function from your one. I just added it to demonstrate another example of where you might return a list from a function.

Comment: ahh I see okay. I was going to say. Thanks for the lengthly explanation- all of it makes sense now! Much appreciated