# Why does an object exist in two sum solution?

Tags: javascript

The Two Sum problem states that given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target. We can’t use the same element twice.

I am trying to understand the point of defining an object in the following Leetcode solution to this problem. I understand that instead of using brute force, the code is geared toward finding the complement (the number which when added to itself, would equalize the target) in order to return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target. How does the object relate to the complement? If I am asking the wrong way, I can better explain. Just trying to learn.

Example:

```
Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,
Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9,
return [0, 1].

function twoSum(nums, target) {
let numObj = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    let complement = target - nums[i];
    if (numObj[complement] !== undefined) {
      return [numObj[complement], i];
    }
    numObj[nums[i]] = i;
  }
}
```

Comment: This might help: [Two-sum Leetcode explanation, Hashmap, Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59612976/5648954)

Comment: Got it. The reason we set an empty object is to store the keys and values as we loop through each option. Wow, so simple. Thanks