# Im trying to find the index of some elements in an array, but I redefined the array to get said elements and if I make a copy it gets redefined aswell

Tags: javascript, scope, reference

I'm solving the leetcode TwoSum problem in javascript. I made a search algorithm that alters the nums array until the first and last indexes are the correct numbers to add to the sum. Then I try to search through an original of the nums array before I altered it to find the indexes of the correct numbers in the original array, but the problem is the saved copy array gets redefined as I alter the first array. Then I can't check against it and find the correct indexes. I tried defining original as a function or even a class, but neither worked; how do I keep it from changing?

```
const searchAlgorithm = (nums, target) => {
    nums = nums.sort((a, b)=>a-b);
    while(true){
        total = nums[0]+nums[nums.length-1];
            if(total>target){
                nums.splice(nums.length-1, 1);
            }
            else{
                if(total==target){
                    answers = [nums[0], nums[nums.length-1]];
                    return answers;
                }
                else{
                    nums.splice(0, 1);
                }
            }
    }
}


const twoSum = (nums, target)=>{
    original = nums;
    [num1, num2] = searchAlgorithm(nums, target);
    answers = [original.indexOf(num1, 0), original.indexOf(num2, 0)];
    return (answers);
}

console.log(twoSum([3,6,8,2,11], 5));
```

Comment: I found a previous question that gave me the solution of slicing original. However, I'm still curious if they're any more conventional answers and if this is a problem because arrays are reference types. 
My solution:`let original = nums.slice();`

Comment: Yeah, to stop the array from being modified you need to make a copy of it like you've done, or not modify it at all in `searchAlgorithm`. A more conventional way of solving this is to [use an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59612976/5648954)

Answer (score 0):

when you do original = nums , it is only giving you 2 names but both are referring to same array(same memory location) hence changing one will change the other. for this you need to do a deep copy(deep cloning) of the array. original = someDeepCopyFunction(nums)